# Can we make Gold in a Lab?

Tags: atoms, metal, nuclear

Can we make Gold in a Lab? Is it possible to make changes in metals that will create Gold? and How?
I have tried to search something related to this but didn't get any good results.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Depends on the lab actually. http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-lead-can-be-turned-into-gold/ You need to be in the fanciest most advanced labs in the world to create gold from lead and prove you can! That gold won't be worthwhile though.

Comment: @MARamezani gold was made from mercury over 90 years ago http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01505658

Comment: Thanks @DavePhD! That was good to know, but I wasn't bringing in records, just put there an example. I don't say that article is fully credible, though.

Comment: it seem that making gold from lead is more difficult than from mercury

Comment: I once read (in a pop sci magazine for kids, so I have no idea how valid this info is) that the easiest metal to turn into gold is...platinum! Unfortunately, you're significantly decreasing its value by doing so...

Comment: @chipbuster That's what I heard too!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, gold has been made from mercury.

See "[Transmutation of Mercury by Fast Neutrons](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.60.473)" Phys. Rev. 60, 473